# Can I modify a program shortcut target to close the initial startup window?

Tags: command-line

I have a program that is always starting up with an annoying 'Register Now?' window.  I do not wish to register ever and would love to not have to close it every time.

Is this possible? I know you can modify the target by adding ' -command' after the "target_path" but I don't know what command I need.

To close the window by the keyboard you press TAB then ENTER.

Comment: To be sure: Is this Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what program you're trying to do this. Some allow, others don't. Most probably, there's no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using a Windows script via Windows Script Host. I'm can't test this for you, but a script along these lines should start you in the right direction:

```
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"); #create shell
WshShell.Run("YOUR PROGRAM HERE");           # run your program
WScript.Sleep(100);                          # wait for it to launch
WshShell.AppActivate("YOUR PROGRAM HERE");   # bring your program to the front
WScript.Sleep(100);
WshShell.SendKeys("{TAB}");
WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

Save that to RunMyApp.js or something and give it a go!

References:
[Writing JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cte3c772(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [SendKeys Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.85).aspx)